# Почему очередь не доступна из Thread?

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-3.x, очередь

Имеется следующий код:

```
def flush_queue_to_stdin(sin, queue):
  while True:
      try:
          o = queue.get_nowait()
          sin.write(o)
      except Empty:
          print('Empty!!!')
          break
  sin.close()

q = Queue()
q.put(some_input.encode('UTF-8'))
t = Thread(target=flush_queue_to_stdin, args=(process.stdin, q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

q.put(some_input.encode('UTF-8'))
```

`process` - процесс, открытый `Popen` процесс, точно готовый считать что-то с `stdin`.

По идее оба вызова `q.put` должны запихать в очередь закодированную в `bytes` строку `some_input`. На практике же доходит только первый вызов (до запуска `Thread`). Почему так и как исправить?

---

**UPD**. `Thread` выводил первый элемент из очереди и после этого умирал. Вот и все.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дополнении к `daemon=True` проблеме, описанной в [ответе @andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423648/23044),  `Empty` может выброшено ещё до того как второй `q.put()` метод был вызван, то есть

- Питон может вызвать `t.start()`
- переключится на только что созданный поток (в CPython из-за GIL, только один поток может исполнять Питон-код за раз)
- и выполнить пару итераций цикла с `q.get_nowait()` -- всё до переключения назад на основной поток.

Поэтому `break` уже может произойти *до того* как второй `q.put()` имел шанс исполнится.

Реализуется ли подобный сценарий или нет, может зависеть от конкретной реализации GIL (версии Питона) и используемых параметров.

---

Более надёжный и простой способ -- использовать специальное значение, чтобы обозначить конец ввода (sentinel):

```
def flush_queue_to_stdin(sin, queue):
    with sin: # call sin.close() even if an exception happens
        for chunk in iter(queue.get, None): # stop on None
            sin.write(chunk)
```

Чтобы дождаться конца ввода можно либо добавить `t.join()` в главном потоке или убрать `daemon=True`:

```
q = Queue()
q.put(some_input.encode('UTF-8'))
t = Thread(target=flush_queue_to_stdin, args=(process.stdin, q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

q.put(some_input.encode('UTF-8'))
q.put(None) # signal: no more input
t.join() # wait for I/O in the child thread
```

Answer (score 3):

Раз автор не потрудился объяснить самостоятельно, попробую объяснить я.

Поток при `daemon=True` [убивается](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) сразу после того, как завершатся все не-daemon потоки (в частности, основной поток), и, соответственно, в приведённом примере он просто не успевает ничего сделать. (К тому же появляются ещё какие-то побочные эффекты: у меня иногда весь процесс просто виснет, а не завершается.)

Добавление простейшего `time.sleep(1)` в конце или `t.join()` или просто отключение `daemon=True` проблему решает.

Но и после этого через несколько запусков можно заметить, что второе добавление в очередь `some_input` не попадает в поток: это уже из-за `get_nowait`, который успевает выкинуть исключение `Empty` ещё до того, как второй элемент будет добавлен в очередь. Лучше, наверно, заменить его на `get(timeout=1)` или вообще переделать всё на простой `get()`.